# Wildcard in an if statement with a variable as a count

Tags: php

```
if ($acc_number=='___001*') {

//add to $number


}
else{
 //skip
}
```

I want to put this in a preg_match but I'm not sure how I can do this. I want there to be 3 digits before 001 then infinite after. Then after to add there information to a variable called $number.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do something like this:

```
if (preg_match("/^([0-9]{3})001([0-9]{0,})$/", $acc_number)) {
    // Add to $number
}
```

I'm not a regular expression expert, so I'm no sure if there is a better/shorter pattern for this.

Comment: Try to use the "^" at the beginning of the pattern and "$" at the end. Like in the pattern i used in the statement above :)